# Output sometimes fail

Tags: c

I am trying to find the Month Gross Salary using C program. My Output sometimes fails. Putting the Code and Output underneath:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main() {
  int id;
  float hours;
  float mgsalary;
  clrscr();
  printf(
      " Press ID  : \n Press 1 if Staff: \n Press 2 if Supervisor: \n Press 3 if Manager: \n Press 4 if President: \n");
  scanf("%d", &id);
  printf(" Enter hours per week \n");
  scanf("%f", &hours);
  if (id == 1) {
    printf(" Position ID: 1 \n");
    mgsalary = (hours * 62.5) * 4.28;
    printf(" Positon/Rank: Staff \n");
    printf(" Rate per hour: 62.5 php \n");
    printf(" Monthly Gross Salary : %f php \n ", mgsalary);
  } else if (id == 2) {
    mgsalary = (hours * 125) * 4.28;
    printf(" Position ID: 2 \n");
    printf(" Position/Rank: Supervisor \n");
    printf(" Rate per hour: 125 php \n");
    printf(" Monthly Gross Salary : %f php \n", mgsalary);
  } else if (id == 3) {
    mgsalary = (hours * 187.5) * 4.28;
    printf(" Position ID: 3 \n");
    printf(" Position/Rank: Manager \n");
    printf(" Rate per hour: 187.5 php \n");
    printf(" Monthly Gross Salary : %f php \n", mgsalary);
  } else if (id == 4) {
    mgsalary = (hours * 375) * 4.28;
    printf(" Position ID: 4 \n");
    printf(" Position/Rank: President \n");
    printf(" Rate per hour: 375 php \n");
    printf(" Monthly Gross Salary: %f php \n", mgsalary);
  } else
    printf(" Invalid Input");
  getch();
}
```

// Running the program (Output)

```
Press 1 if Staff: 
Press 2 if Supervisor:
Press 3 if Manager: 
Press 4 if President:
```

// I had selected Staff by pressing 1

```
Enter numbers of hours work:
```

// I had entered 33 as the number of hours work

```
Position ID: 1 
Positon/Rank: Staff 
Rate per hour: 62.5 php 
Monthly Gross Salary : 8872.5000 php (sometimes it came out 10000000.000 php or null)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. As a side note, make sure that your main is int (not void), use `switch` instead of the cascaded `if`, and indent your code.

Comment: My instructor required us to use Turbo C, so i should change it int into void

Comment: Curious, was the output `... 8872.5000 ...` or `... 8827.500000 ...`?  Are you posting a true copy of output?

Comment: Turbo C or not, the prototype of the main function is `int main()`.

Comment: Code does not check if input succeeded - best to check the return value of `scanf()`.  With errant input, `id` or `hours` can propagate uninitialized leading to strange output - (UB).  Failed to re-produce even OP's "correct" output.  Post needs more info/clarity.

Comment: OT: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions,, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the variable `mgsalary` is declared as `float`, however all the numeric literals are `double`  this results in the compiler modifying the values through an implicit conversion.  implicit conversions are dangerous.  Suggest appending a `f` on the end of each literal

Answer (score -1):

the following proposed code:

1. eliminates the non-portable calls from `conio.h`
2. properly checks for `scanf()` errors
3. formats the code for readability
4. uses a `switch()` statement rather than a series of `if()` statements
5. properly declares the 'magic' numbers with meaningful names
6. makes use of a `enum` statement to give user selection input meaningful names
7. properly declares all literal values as `float` rather than the default `double`
8. cleanly compiles
9. uses a valid signature for the `main()` function
10. EDIT naming, etc corrected per comments

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // perror(), getchar(), fprintf(), printf(), scanf()
//#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

#define WEEKS_PER_MONTH           4.28f
#define STAFF_WEEKLY_RATE        62.5f
#define SUPERVISOR_WEEKLY_RATE  125.0f
#define MANAGER_WEEKLY_RATE     187.5f
#define PRESIDENT_WEEKLY_RATE   375.0f

enum 
{
    dummy,
    STAFF,
    SUPERVISOR,
    MANAGER,
    PRESIDENT
};


int main( void ) 
{
    int id;
    float hours;
    float mgsalary;
    int ch;



    /* clrscr();  Suggest using the ANSI excape sequences */
    printf( "%s\n",
          " Press ID  : \n"
          " Press 1 if Staff: \n"
          " Press 2 if Supervisor: \n"
          " Press 3 if Manager: \n"
          " Press 4 if President: \n");
    id = getchar();

    printf(" Enter hours per week \n");
    if( scanf("%f", &hours) != 1 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf for hours failed\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }


    switch( id )
    {
      case STAFF:
        printf(" Position ID: 1 \n");
        mgsalary = (hours * STAFF_WEEKLY_RATE) * WEEKS_PER_MONTH;
        printf(" Positon/Rank: Staff \n");
        printf(" Rate per hour: 62.5 php \n");
        printf(" Monthly Gross Salary : %f php \n ", mgsalary);
        break;

      case SUPERVISOR:
        mgsalary = (hours * SUPERVISOR_WEEKLY_RATE) * WEEKS_PER_MONTH;
        printf(" Position ID: 2 \n");
        printf(" Position/Rank: Supervisor \n");
        printf(" Rate per hour: 125 php \n");
        printf(" Monthly Gross Salary : %f php \n", mgsalary);
        break;

      case MANAGER:
        mgsalary = (hours * MANAGER_WEEKLY_RATE) * WEEKS_PER_MONTH;
        printf(" Position ID: 3 \n");
        printf(" Position/Rank: Manager \n");
        printf(" Rate per hour: 187.5 php \n");
        printf(" Monthly Gross Salary : %f php \n", mgsalary);
        break;

      case PRESIDENT:
        mgsalary = (hours * PRESIDENT_WEEKLY_RATE) * WEEKS_PER_MONTH;
        printf(" Position ID: 4 \n");
        printf(" Position/Rank: President \n");
        printf(" Rate per hour: 375 php \n");
        printf(" Monthly Gross Salary: %f php \n", mgsalary);
        break;

      default:
        printf(" Invalid Menu Selection\n");
        break;
    } /* end switch */

    while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n' );
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: `BASE_RATE               4.28f` it is not some  base rate it is number of weeks per month.

Comment: @kiranBiradar,  if the OP had included some comments or meaningful names, that little 'opps' would not have happened.  BTW: since you edited my answer, how come you didn't fix the naming?  So I'm going to roll back your modifications.  If you want to make those changes, then make them correctly.  You might also want to fix my spelling of `MULTIPLIER` in several places

Comment: I thought of modifying it. But currently I'm using mobile, it is difficult to modify big changes using mobile.

Comment: Between op is telling `he is trying to calculate the monthly gross by taking number of hours per weeks`

Comment: `#define STAFF_MULITPLIER        6.25f` should be `#define STAFF_MULITPLIER        62.5f`